# Error when getting all model names in django app

Tags: django, django-models, routes, multi-database

I am using different dbs inside my django application and while db routing, i am trying to get all models using

```
all_models = dict([(name.lower(), cls) for name, cls in app.models.__dict__.items() \
 if isinstance(cls, type)])
```

While running migrations, i am getting error "name app is not defined".

This is my routers.py

```
from .models import *



  allmodels = dict([(name.lower(), cls) for name, cls in 
  app.models.__dict__.items() \
 if isinstance(cls, type)])

class MyDBRouter(object):

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """ reading model based on params """
    return getattr(model.params, 'db')

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """ writing model based on params """
    return getattr(model.params, 'db')

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name = None, **hints):
    """ migrate to appropriate database per model """
    model = allmodels.get(model_name)
    return(model.params.db == db)
```

Settings.py
https://pastebin.com/0XdpqxkJ

Comment: Can you show your `settings.py`

Comment: what database you are using

Comment: postgresql db @VishalPandey

Comment: @VishalPandey added settings.py https://pastebin.com/0XdpqxkJ

Comment: Can you tell me in which file you are getting this error

Comment: @VishalPandey if you see only routers.py has this line. So it is from routers.py

Comment: As I can see  this line so where is app variable `app.models.__dict__.items() \`

Comment: Because most of the name error is something when you didn't define name and call it